# Including Javascript codes with @stack not working

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-components

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I have a `master.blade.php` goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!-- including scripts and stylesheets -->
   </head>
   <body>
      @yield('content')

      <script src="/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      @stack('scripts')
   </body>
</html>
```

Then at `content.blade.php`, I added this as my dynamic content:

```
@extends('admin.master')

@section('content')
   {{ $title }}
   ...
   {{ $slot }}
@endsection
```

After that I have created some new file and used the components like this:

```
@component('admin.layouts.content' , ['title' => 'example file'])
   @slot('breadcrumb')
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Example File</li>
   @endslot
   ...
@endcomponent

@push('scripts')
   <script>
   console.log(1); // to check if the js codes can be run on page
   </script>
@endpush
```

But the problem is that `@push('scripts')` not working at all! Meaning that this way of including Javascript codes is wrong.

So how can I properly include them in my example page properly?

Note that I don't want to include js codes in `content.blade.php` because it loads in every single page!

Comment: That is not how you create a component anymore in laravel 8 [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to swap the order of `@push` and `@component`

```php
@push('scripts')
   <script>
   console.log(1); // to check if the js codes can be run on page
   </script>
@endpush

@component('admin.layouts.content' , ['title' => 'example file'])
   @slot('breadcrumb')
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Example File</li>
   @endslot
   ...
@endcomponent
```

I guess it's got something with how blade files are parsed and compiled. So when `@component | <x-component>` comes before `@push`, what probably happens is that the **component** gets rendered by the blade compiler engine and then there's no placeholder for the `@push` directive to merge contents on the stack.

Faced a similar issue once and learnt that when using components the `@push` should come before the `@component | <x-component>` - **order is important** when using **stacks** with component.

Comment: Would you check this related question plz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675459/pushing-javascript-codes-at-blade-does-not-work-out