# pushing javascript codes at blade does not work out

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-components

I have a file called `all.blade.php` which goes like this:

```
@component('admin.layouts.content' , ['title' => 'example file'])
   @slot('breadcrumb')
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Example File</li>
   @endslot
   ...
@endcomponent

@push('scripts')
    <script>
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
            showDenyButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Save',
            denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
        }).then((result) => {
            /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
            }
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

And here is `content.blade.php`:

```
@extends('admin.master')

@section('content')
   {{ $slot }}
@endsection
```

And this is `master.blade.php`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        ...
        @stack('scripts')
     </head>
     <body>
        @yield('content')
     </body>
   </html>
```

Now the problem is `@push('scripts') ... @endpush` does not work out and not showing the sweet alert message.

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue and call the @component and @push together at a blade?

Comment: Please check the console and let me know, It you get any error in browser console.

Comment: @SujithSandeep No not working, the problem is something else. Like I said, I think there's must be a problem with the way I called the `@push` with `@component `

Comment: Okay... I have answered below. Try that also and let me know...

Comment: You can also mention when the script should be running... Like, `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Comment: @SujithSandeep If I put the js code in `master.blade.php` or even `content.blade.php`, **it will work** but I don't know why on earth it does not load in `all.blade.php`

Comment: Or else try using `@push('scripts')` after `@endslot`.i.e.., Inside `@component`.

Comment: @SujithSandeep Finally it worked :). I put the `@stack` at the end body section of master blade and put the `@push .. @endpush` in all.blade.php after the `@slot`

Comment: Thats Great... @japose7523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the order of `@push` and `@component`

```php
@push('scripts')
    <script>
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
            showDenyButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Save',
            denyButtonText: 'Don\'t save',
        }).then((result) => {
            /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
                Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
            }
        })
    </script>
@endpush

@component('admin.layouts.content' , ['title' => 'example file'])
   @slot('breadcrumb')
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Example File</li>
   @endslot
   ...
@endcomponent
```

Another option would be to convert the **master** into component

```html
<!-- resources/views/components/admin/master.blade.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        ...
        {{ $scripts ?? '' }}
     </head>
     <body>
        {{ $slot }}
     </body>
   </html>
```

And convert **content** into a component

```html
<!-- resources/views/components/admin/layouts/content.blade.php -->
<x-admin.master>
    <x-slot:scripts>
       {{ $scripts ?? '' }}
    </x-slot>
    {{ $slot }}

   <!-- Any other slots etc -->
</x-admin.master>
```

Then you can write the **all.blade.php** as

```html
<x-admin.layouts.content>
    <x-slot:scripts>
        <script>
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
                showDenyButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Save',
                denyButtonText: 'Don\'t save',
            }).then((result) => {
                /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
                } else if (result.isDenied) {
                    Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
                }
            })
        </script>
    </x-slot>
    <h1>All</h1>
</x-admin.layouts.content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl+U` to check if that component is rendered to its position. Also mention, If you are using Swal a JS library so did the actual Swallibrary code load before calling the fire() function.

Last please check the browser console option to identify if it was some JS error, not the blade.

Comment: If I cut and paste the js codes into head section of `master.blade.php` it will work out fine but now it does not load it at all! There's a problem with the way I'm calling the `@push`

Comment: In fact I don't want to load this js code in every file, just in the `all.blade.php` file